# dynamically create a javascript/jquery multilevel array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is driving me crazy.

Assuming I have this:

```
var tags = ["art","wedding"];
var containers = ["artcon","weddingcon"];
var limits = [5,15];
```

How can I create this type of multilevel array like this structure?

```
var testarr = [
    "art" = [
        "container" = "artcon",
        "limit" = 5,
    ],
    "wedding" = [
       "container" = "weddingcon",
       "limit" = 15,
    ]
];
```

Best regards.

Comment: It's called an object - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and return object

```js
var tags = ["art", "wedding"];
var containers = ["artcon", "weddingcon"];
var limits = [5, 15];

var result = tags.reduce((res, e, i) => {
  res[e] = {container: containers[i], limit: limits[i]}
  return res;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: this is great. had no idea about reduce. this produced exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

only need a `for` loop

```
var tags = ["art","wedding"];
var containers = ["artcon","weddingcon"];
var limits = [5,15];
//
var obj =[];
for(i in tags){
    obj[tags[i]]=[containers[i],limits[i]];
}
console.log(obj);
//
```

response:

```
[art: Array[2], wedding: Array[2]]
art:Array[2]
 0:"artcon"
 1:5
length:2
wedding:Array[2]
 0:"weddingcon"
 1:15
length:2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var testarr = {
    "art": {
        "container": "artcon",
        "limit": 5,
    },
    "wedding": {
        "container": "weddingcon",
        "limit": 15,
    }
};
```

This is a pretty simple modification from the idea you had. Take note of how in object declaration, we always use `:` instead of `=`. Also, object declaration uses curly braces instead of square brackets.

What can we do with this object? We can loop through it, though not *quite* as reliably as we can an array.
For example, we can do `for (key in testarr)`, and the loop will execute twice, one with `key` being `"art"`, and one with it being `"wedding"`. There are some caveats to this...but in such a simple use case you'll probably be fine.

Although, please let me know if your question was how do you convert those three objects **via code** into that object structure, because right now it seems like you'd just like to understand how objects or "multilevel arrays" work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tags = ["art","wedding"];
var containers = ["artcon","weddingcon"];
var limits = [5,15];

testarr = new Array();
    
for(i in tags){
   var obj = {};
   obj[tags[i]] = { container: containers[i], limit: limits[i] };
   testarr.push(obj)
}

console.log(testarr);
console.log(testarr[0]);
console.log(testarr[1]);
```

Array Result:

```
[
    { "art": {
               "container": "artcon",
               "limit": 5,
             }
    },
    { "wedding": {
                  "container": "weddingcon",
                  "limit": 15,
                 }
    }
];
```

---

```js
var tags = ["art","wedding"];
var containers = ["artcon","weddingcon"];
var limits = [5,15];

 testarr = new Array();
    for(i in tags){
       testarr.push({tag: tags[i], container: containers[i], limit: limits[i] })
    }

console.log(testarr);
console.log(testarr[0]);
console.log(testarr[1]);
```

Array Result:

```
[
    { "tag": "art",
      "container": "artcon",
      "limit": 5
    },
    { "tag": "wedding",
      "container": "weddingcon",
      "limit": 15
    }
];
```